# Trying to play HTML5 audio on a mouseover event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, mouseover

I am unsure why this script is not working as it should I think and when I run it no errors happen. I am also running qTip 2 if that makes any difference as to how this script interacts.

Here are my scripts.

**JS**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

var growlSound = $j("#growlSound")[0];
$j("#growl")
    .mouseenter(function() {
            growlSound.play();
    });

var laughSound = $j("#laughSound")[0];
$j("#laugh")
    .mouseenter(function() {
            laughSound.play();
    });

</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<audio id="growlSound" preload="auto">
                            <source src="/messages4u/2011/images/october/growl.ogg">
                            <source src="/messages4u/2011/images/october/growl.mp3">
                            Your browser does not support HTML5 Audio. Please Upgrade Your Browser.
                    </audio>
                            <audio id="laughSound" preload="auto">
                            <source src="/messages4u/2011/images/october/laugh.ogg">
                            <source src="/messages4u/2011/images/october/laugh.mp3">
                            Your browser does not support HTML5 Audio. Please Upgrade Your Browser.
                    </audio>
    <p><img src="/messages4u/2011/images/october/halloween4.jpg" width="600" border="0" usemap="#Map" class="center" style="width: 600px;" />
      <map name="Map" id="Map">
        <area class="growl" id="growl" style="cursor:default;" shape="rect" coords="117,118,225,223" href="#" />
        <area class="laugh" id="laugh" style="cursor:default;" shape="rect" coords="255,244,308,292" href="#" />
      </map>
</p>
```

As You can see I am attempting to play audio on a mouseover event. I cannot get this to work and yet I am unsure where the error lies.

***UPDATE*** - It appears the `mouseenter`event is not working.

Comment: "Script does not work" is a poor question title. Please try again.

Comment: have you looked to see if there are errors using firebug, or an integrated javascript debugger?

Comment: Firebug does not produce any errors. And Dreamweaver shows no errors when I created the code.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal - The issue is in the question. While the title may not be great it states the issue. The Script does not work...

Comment: @Lynda: That's not the issue. Next time fix the question title please, so that it may benefit future visitors in discerning the topic of your question; thomasrutter has done a good job this time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be some other factors in play. I created a simpler example here; seems to be working (in Chrome):

http://jsfiddle.net/5PnCt/2/

It could be that:

- Your audio files aren't correctly linked
- You are, somehow, failing to trigger the mouseenter event
- You aren't correctly binding the event

To test the second case, add something like:

```
        console.log('playing');
```

...to one of your mouseenter handlers. If the event is triggered, you should see the log message.

For the third case, make sure that you either put your scripts AFTER the HTML they affect, or you use the following wrapper to make sure they don't execute until the HTML loads:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function(){
    ...code goes here...
});
```

You can't select and bind events to an element if it doesn't exist on the page, so the order of your code is important. Using document.ready is one way to get around this issue; it tells jQuery to wait until the page completely loads before attempting to execute the script.

Comment: I had it display the controls. The mouseover is not triggering the files to play. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Hmm, so the files aren't playing, but you're sure the event is firing? Could be that the paths aren't right. When you go to [yourserver]/messages4u/2011/images/october/growl.ogg, does an ogg file play/download? You probably know this, but starting the link with a "/" will cause the browser to look at the root (example.com/[pathname]), not the current location (example.com/mywebpage/[pathname]).

Comment: Yes they are working. I turned the control on and I can play the files by hitting play without an issue yet they do not fire on mouseover. Here is the page I am working on - http://tinyurl.com/3zceysj - The Devil looking face and the scarecrow/witch to the left are the two events that should fire a sound. The controls about the picture are there for testing only and normally will not be displayed.

Comment: One other note, I do not see the log so I assume the mouseenter is not firing?

Comment: Looks like the problem is that you're selecting DOM elements before they exist on the page! Updating my answer with the fix.

Comment: YOU ARE MY HERO! IT'S BEAUTIFUL! To hear ghastly ghostly voices groaning at me => I hope you get lots of treats. Thank you for mine!